# Proper noun in compounds

Tags: compound

I'm wondering if there's a rule for compound words containing a proper noun. For instance could

> Domestic Ferrari Exhibition

be translated into

> Heimferrariausstellung

or

> Ferrari Heimausstellung

or should it be always written separately?

Comment: Are you talking about a domestic exhibition of Ferraris or an exhibition of domestic Ferraris?

Comment: Domestic exhibition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is no *general* rule for that, regardless of whether there is proper noun involved or not. You have to know the *exact meaning* of what you want to translate.

I tried to figure out the exact meaning of "domestic" for your particular example, and think that you wouldn't translate it with the noun "Heim-" in this case, but rather with the adjective "heimisch":

> heimische Ferrari-Ausstellung

("heimisch" here would mean "happening locally", or maybe "in your home town")

(*Edited*: As Wrzlprmft pointed out in a comment: If this is supposed to refer to "domestic Ferraris", then you would rather translate it as "Ausstellung heimischer Ferraris", but that sounds a bit strange for me, in German and in English...)

The main influencing factors for the meaning are the *order* of the words, and the hyphenation. For example, if you translated it as "Heimferrariausstellung", then people might wonder what a "Heimferrari" might be. One could disambiguate this by using "Heim-Ferrariausstellung", but again, I think that "heimisch" is more appropriate. Similarly, the form "Ferrari Heimausstellung" sounds more like an exhibition of *homes* (maybe interior designs or furniture) that is somehow related to "Ferrari".

---

A famous example for the dangerous ambiguities that may arise here is the "Girl('s) Trade School", which, as a compound of "Mädchen", "Handel" and "Schule" should be translated as

> Mädchen-Handelsschule *(business/trading school for girls)*

and definitely not as

> Mädchenhandels-Schule *(school for girl trafficking)*

Answer (score 0):

Quotation [from Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenname#Morphologie_und_Wortbildung):

> Bei der Bildung von Substantiven durch Komposition mit Eigennamen wird
>   oft die Kopplung mit Bindestrich gegenüber der sonst üblichen
>   Zusammenschreibung bevorzugt. Dies gilt besonders, wenn der Eigenname
>   orthographisch nicht integriert ist (Mekong-Offensive, aber
>   Italienaufenthalt) oder die Gefahr einer Missdeutung entstehen könnte
>   (Fischer-Initiative).

"Heimferrariausstellung" is wrong. You cannot put a proper noun into the middle of a word. "Ferrari Heimausstelung" sounds ok, though not correctly written (see "[Leerzeichen in Komposita](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leerzeichen_in_Komposita)"). "Ferrari-Heimausstellung" looks better.

Names of streets and other geographic places are often written not separated: *Goethestraße, Siemensstraße, Schillerplatz* etc.